# What are the 1 2 3 settings on the back of The Blue Snowball?

Tags: microphone

The Blue Snowball has settings on the back controlled by a dip switch that says 1 2 3. What do these do?

Googling for it I get a bunch of bad results (html numbered lists) and [this manual which doesn't tell me much](https://www.fullcompass.com/common/files/3298-BlueMicrophonesSnowballUserManual.pdf)

Comment: @Mark it wasn't easy for me to find that product manual. Or that information. That's why I went through the effort to add it to the information here. My assumption is others would like this to be found easily on google.

Comment: If the question isn't your cup of tea that's fine. When I google for it the first result is https://www.adc.ucsc.edu/tutorials/audio/blue-snowball-microphone-user-guide which has nothing to do with it. Lists with `1 2 3` come up. For me the first manual that comes up is https://www.fullcompass.com/common/files/3298-BlueMicrophonesSnowballUserManual.pdf That manual doesn't have the information. Amazingly Position 1 and Position 2 in that manual are the same. But alas, why do I have to defend myself here?

Comment: I solved my own problem and I tried to give back to your community. If you don't like this question isn't it easier to ignore it? Consider this. I've helped over 4 times the people you have (people reached) with my 15 questions and 4 answers. 4 of my questions are famous, 6 are notable and 7 are popular. I think throwing shade at this one because it was easy for you to find the answer is a pretty bad idea. ;) Give it some time. This will be easier than navigating the manual for others, and it will index over the other trash. I'm giving back. I expect nothing here.

Comment: @Mark I suggest you read the [Code of Conduct](https://sound.stackexchange.com/conduct). "L2Google" is explicitly mentioned there as unacceptable as one of the very first things.

Comment: @AJHenderson isn’t this considered a consumer audio question though? I flagged it as that the first day.

Comment: @timinycricket not really.  The consumer audio bit refers primarily to HiFi , home theater and communications, not recording and blue yeti is really prosumer rather than pure consumer.  They are primarily used in a production recording context, whether for streaming or basic audio recording.

Comment: @AJHenderson OK. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Timinycricket looking at the details of the close reason, the key part is that it's consumer "consumption".  The more formal way of putting it is "non-production" but "production" was also a bit unclear.  Basically if you are doing audio content production, even if it's consumer gear, it's on topic, as long as the goal is a consumable product and not something like for personal use.  (Aka, how do I record class audio so I can review it after class would be off topic.  How do I record the lecture's I'm giving so I can share them with my class? would be on topic.

Comment: The key part of the reason behind my close vote was that it is simply repeating information that can be easily found by anyone who bothers to visit the manufacturer website.

Comment: @Mark (innocent follow up) this is now a famous question. We've helped over 10,000 people who also had a difficulty finding this information. This question is in the top 174 on the site, by view count.

Comment: My position hasn't changed. We don't want to be reproducing system manuals on this site. Please for the love of God, don't tag me in any more of your comments.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Referencing both [manuals for the Snowball Blue Microphone](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cd.bluemic.com/pdf/snowball/manual.pdf) (and [this manual](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cd.bluemic.com/pdf/manuals/snowball/Blue_Snowball_QuickStart-EN.pdf)) which provide similar information with different descriptions of the settings, this switch controls the pickup pattern,

1. Position 1,

   - Setting: Cardioid (capsule),
   - Applications: speech, vocals, podcasting
   - Picks up sound from the front, ideal for podcasting, game streaming or recording vocals and instruments
2. Position 2

   - Setting: Cardioid (capsule) with -10dB pad
   - Applications: live music, loud sound sources
   - Reduces mic sensitivity so loud instruments or vocalists come in crystal clear and distortion free
3. Position 3

   - Setting: Omnidirectional (capsule)
   - Applications: conferences, interviews, environmental recordings
   - Picks up sound all around the mic, perfect for conference calls or recording a group of musicians

Comment: Far too many people think it's an off switch when used for conference calls.  So the next time you use, it's moved to the wrong position.  Then it's only going to pick people in front of it.